# URL redirect shell script provided with Magento EE 1.13.1, what are they meant for?

Tags: magento-enterprise, redirect, ee-1.13, url-rewrite, ee-1.13.0.1

Magento EE 1.13.1 is provided with a bunch of scripts that are meant to help in the migration from previous Url management to the new one (Url Rewrite -> Url Redirect).

We have 4 scripts in `/shell/` :

1. url_migration_to_1_13.php (documented [here](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/ee-112-and-earlier-url-redirect-script#upgrade-manual-post-upgrade-11302-run))
2. url_migration_from_1_13_0_0_to_1_13_0_2.php (documented [here](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/ee-11300-or-ee-11301-url-redirect-script))
3. umt113_conflict.php
4. umt113_redirect.php

I cannot find any info related to scripts 3 and 4 ... any idea ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

They are both used by *`./shell/url_migration_to_1_13.php`* to execute migration logic in separate processes:

```
$child = 'php -f ' . dirname(__FILE__) . '/umt113_conflict.php --';
$processesCheck = "ps x | grep \"$child\" | grep -v grep";
for(; $batches; $batches--) {
    $output = '';
    if ($threadCount == 1) {
        exec($child . " $i $batchSize >> " . dirname(__FILE__) . "/url_migration.log 2>&1", $output, $status);
    } else {
        waitForChildren($processesCheck, $threadCount);
        exec($child . " $i $batchSize >> " . dirname(__FILE__) . "/url_migration.log 2>&1 &", $output, $status);
    }
    $progressBar->update(++$i, '');
}
```

Comment: mmm... I wonder why they are not inside /shell/lib/